# Does glTexImage* use the external format parameters when no data is passed?

Tags: opengl

When calling `glTexImage*` with a null pointer to merely allocate the texture but not specify any data, are the pixel format parameters (`format` and `type` from the [manpage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml), that is) used at all? I don't find any explicit explanation of this in the manpage.

I figure that they aren't *actually* used, but are they so completely ignored that I can just pass nonsense (like zero, for instance) to them, or do I have to specify something that makes sense somehow? If the latter, are they subject to any kind of constraints depending on the internal format, or can I just pass any valid constant and have it work, like `GL_RGBA` even though I'm creating a texture with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` internal format?

Comment: Do not think of this as an "external" format. I know since the other parameter is called "internal" this is tempting. If you understand that it is actually the ***pixel transfer format*** then it will make sense to you that if you do not invoke a pixel transfer (e.g. `data` is NULL) then the format is irrelevant.

Comment: But do not think for a second that this means you can supply any random enumerant you want. The GL may still validate the pixel transfer format against the valid matching set of internal and transfer formats even if no operation is necessary. Your question was whether it is "used," and short of parameter validation the answer would be no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_INVALID_ENUM` is generated if type is not a type constant.

`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if internalFormat is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, `DEPTH_COMPONENT16`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`, or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`, and format is not `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`.

So yes, you still have to specify correct values. Even if some implementation will ignore it, other may issue an error.